How to set Label text in .net MAUI using M2MQTT from uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt?
I am trying to set the text of a label with the message I get from MQTT. The message also arrives because I can output it in the debug console. I think it is a problem with the UI thread but I have no idea how to solve this problem.
Here is the function which receives the data/message:
private async void client_MqttMsgPublishReceivedAsync(object sender, MqttMsgPublishEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string msg = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Message Received: " + msg);

        await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() =>
        {
            if (datenPage != null)
            {
                datenPage.UpdateContent(msg);
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("DatenPage is null.");
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("MQTT", $"Error: {ex.Message}", "OK");
    }
}

this is the function which should set the label text:
public void UpdateContent(string newText)
{
    if (temp != null)
    {
        temp.Text = newText;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Label changed to: {newText}");
    }
    else
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Label 'temp' is null.");
    }
}

Does anyone have an example of how to display a received MQTT message in a label?
I expect the mqtt message to be displayed as the text of the label.

what is datenPage?  How does MQTT get a reference to it?

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow! Please provide a MRE https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

@Jason datenPage is basically my class for the "Data" Tab in my application and UpdateContent is in that class

is it the same instance of the page that is displayed?  Please show how you pass the reference to your MQTT class

I don't see any reason to use below to update the label text value.
await MainThread.InvokeOnMainThreadAsync(() => {}; 

In my personal experience
 MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { });

have worked with Mqtt. Since the update needs to be on Uithread you can try few things.
1.) Use   Dispatcher.Dispatch(() => { }); to update the text.
2.) Use Binding to set the Label text value. So that you can use OnPropertyChanged() to update view.
  <Label Text="{Binding MyLabelText}"/>

in xaml.cs
 private string _myLableText = string.Empty;
 public string MyLableText
 {
     get { return _myLableText; }
     set
     {
         _myLableText= value;
         OnPropertyChanged(MyLableText);
     }
 }

Make sure to set BindingContext = this;
